# Recover ancient versions of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I was running different postgresql versions. And accidentally they were removed. they contained several databases and I want to recover them. I'm wondering if there'a a command line in linux that allows me to recover lost data.

Your help would be so precious!

Thank you in advance

Comment: The Postgres executable files and the databases' data files are separate. Which files were removed?

Comment: The installations of the different postgresql versions that existed in my distant server which were removed

Comment: What do you mean with "installations", the executables or the data files? Do you know the names of the directories that were removed?

Comment: I accidentally removed the executables such as postgresql-8.4, postgresql-9.1. And I believe when you remove or unistall an app all the data inside is also gone. I wonder if there is a way to recover everything was unistalled

Comment: The actual data is stored somewhere else (see [PostgreSQL database default location on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004523/postgresql-database-default-location-on-linux)).

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a backup of the entire data directory for each.
2. Reinstall the version of postgresql you need
3. Point its data directory at your existing one

If you are running a packaged version of postgresql then there might be nothing to do for 3

Comment: I want to recover the ancient postgresql versions wich contains some databases. To be more clear. I wanted to install a newest version of postgresql then I accidentally removed the other versions that were previously installed. Now I want to recover this versions to have the ancient databases. I don't know if it's possible but if there's a way it would be great